# MAC filtering for Network

Tags: networking, lan, wan, traffic-filtering

I have TP link router and I want to block unwanted users on my network so I used MAC filtering but it has limitation that I can add only 64 users in it to allow on my network but I want to add more users. So How can I block or filter those users if MAC filtering is not an option for me. Is there any tool or some software available for this? 
Also how can I monitor network in effective manner?

Comment: MAC filtering is totally useless, for security purposes. Listening in to your LAN **before registering** into it, and spoofing an allowed MAC is trivial.

Comment: How to secure network then? If MAC filtering is not a good option.

Comment: Use WPA2 to secure a wireless network. It can be broken in about an hour and with about US $75 of S3 time.  That is the best we currently have though as far as homeuser wireless security goes.

Comment: To understand why MAC filtering does not work, see [this post](http://superuser.com/a/528895/121352).

Comment: I want this for my office network. As many of them uses mobile device to access internet. So I want only specific user can access internet.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better to base security on Radius Server and 802.1X access authentication.

802.1X access authentication system is widely used in Ethernet environment as a solution to provide authentication access for clients.
802.1X access authentication is based on “port”，which means the access control and AAA authentications for clients is based on the “port” of NAS (Network Access Server).If the client connects to the port of NAS passes the authentication of Radius Server, then the client can get access to the resources belonging to the NAS, but not the other way around.

[Example configuration](http://www.tp-linkru.com/article/?faqid=787)

Comment: Thank you Nafscript but what you have suggested will not work for me as 802.1X authentication is not available on my TP link router. I need something else.

Comment: @SiddharthMehta What's router model?

Comment: TP-Link TL-R470T+

Comment: @SiddharthMehta It is available when Remote Authentication is selected.